# .htaccess rewrite three filenames into two directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having some problems with using .htaccess to rewrite three filenames.

Basically the url: domain.com/post.php?category=uncategorized&title=title-of-post&id=1

should be rewritten as

domain.com/uncategorized/title-of-post-1

I worked out how to just rewrite one of the filenames (such as the categorized part) but how do I do all three, so that the category will be in one directory, and the second directory will be a merge of the title and id separated by a dash?

This is my code so far:

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on

 # add a trailing slash
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
 RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^([\w\d~%.:-]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I also need the URL to end with a slash. If it is not, it will redirect to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a new rule for `post.php`:

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on

 # add a trailing slash
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
 RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)-([^/-]+)/?$ post.php?category=$1&title=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA]

 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```